# python can not get my all examples right

Tags: python

For my own understanding, I write 2 functions and use my examples to test. Similarly, both 2 functions have 1 example right and one wrong.
1.
def count_from_word_list(tweet, L):
    """(str, list of str) -> int

The first parameter represents a tweet. The second parameter is a list of words. Count how many times any of the words from the list occur in the tweet, and return the total number.

```
>>> count_from_word_list('I like him and I like her',  ["like","her"])
3
>>> count_from_word_list('I like him and he likes me',  ["like","her"])
1

"""

count = 0
for i in L:
    if i in tweet:
        count = count + 1
return count
```

2.
def contains_hashtag(tweet, h):
    """(str, str) -> bool

```
The first parameter represents a tweet, and second parameter represents a hashtag. Return True if and only if the tweet contains the hashtag. 

>>> contains_hashtag('I like #csc120', '#csc120')
True
>>> contains_hashtag('I like #csc120', '#csc')
False
"""

if h in tweet:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 1):

### First function

I assume from your example that the body of your first function looks like

```
def count_from_word_list(tweet, L):
    count = 0
    for i in L:
        if i in tweet:
            count = count + 1
    return count
```

Lets think about what is happening in logical steps:

1. You use `i` to iterate over the list of words to search for.
2. You then test if `i` is in `tweet` using the `in` keyword.

And this is where your error lies. The `in` keyword in python is used to test if something contains something else. Once python sees that the left hand operand to `in` is in the right hand operand, it stops, and does not count all the occurrences of the appearance.

If you want to count the number of times a given list of words appear in string do this instead:

```
def count_occurens_of_words(tweet, word_list):
# create a variable to hold the count in.
# It will be incremented each time we find
# a word in the tweet that contains or matches a
# word from the word_list
count = 0
# for each word in the word_list
for search_word in word_list:
    # for each word in the tweet
    for word in tweet.split(' '):
        # if a word in the tweet contains or matches a word from the word_list
        if search_word == word:
            # increment count
            count += 1
# return count           
return count
```

**Output:**

```
>>> count_occurens_of_words('I like him and he likes me',  ["like","her"])
2
>>> count_occurens_of_words('I like him and he likes her',  ["like","her"])
3
>>>
```

### Second function

Assuming that your second function is something such as this:

```
def contains_hashtag(tweet, h):
    if h in tweet:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

What you need to do is check if any word in the tweet is the hashtag your looking for. When you use `in` even if the hashtag is a substring of another hashtag it will return true. eg.

```
def contains_hashtag(tweet, h):
    for word in tweet.split(' '):
        if word == h:
            return True
```

Comment: For the first function, actually the following is what I want to show:

Comment: >>> count_from_word_list('I like him and I like her',  ["like","her"])
3
>>> count_from_word_list('I like him and he likes me',  ["like","her"])
1

Comment: but when I run them, it shows 3 and 2 respectively instead of 3 and 1

Comment: for the second function, my aim is to check if tweet contains hashtag, if the hashtag is the same as h ,it is true. When h is not the same hashtag or it is only part of the hashtag, it is wrong. Eg: I love #csc120 (h = #csc120 is true but h = #csc12 is wrong although tweet includes #csc12)

Comment: @AndyYang I've edited my question to address your concerns.

Comment: Thanks for your help, now the first function works but the second one, I believe there are still small problems, both examples return False if the following is like:                                                                                        for word in tweet.split(' '):
        if word == h:
            return True
        else:
            return False